# Enable screen zoom via terminal

Tags: terminal, settings, accessibility, zoom

There are two accessibility settings (indicated by the red rectangle in the screenshot below) that allow for zooming into the screen by holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and scrolling the mouse.

Is there a way to enable those settings from the terminal?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On my system, there are four `.plist` files in `~/Library/Preferences/`that get modified when those two checkboxes are checked/unchecked:

- `com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist`
- `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist`
- `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`
- `com.apple.universalaccess.plist`

While one could take the steps to see which *keys* get *added/modified/deleted* and could write a *script* to using `defaults`<sup>1</sup> to change the appropriate *keys* in these files nonetheless, it would just be easier to use **AppleScript** to do it in **System Preferences**, if automating it is what you want.

1. In **Terminal**, use the following *compound command* to create the **file** and open it:

   ```
   touch togzoom; open togzoom
   ```
2. Copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, into the opened `togzoom` **file**.
3. Save and close the **file**.
4. Make the **file** *executable*:

   ```
   chmod u+x togzoom
   ```

I used `togzoom` for: `[tog]gle zoom`

**NOTE:** This will also require giving **Terminal** [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) for this to work properly.

You can now use it from the *directory* it's in using `./togzoom` otherwise `/path/to/togzoom`; however, it's best if you place in into a *directory* that's within your `PATH` *statement*. Then it can be used from anywhere by just `togzoom`, (or whatever you actually named the *executable*).

---

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested and works for me, as coded, on **macOS High Sierra** and **macOS Mojave**; however, a minor change is needed for **macOS Mojave** and is noted in the paragraph after the *code*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        quit application "System Preferences"
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Zoom" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"

tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
    application process "System Preferences" to tell ¬
    window "Accessibility"

    repeat until exists checkbox "Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    set UKSTZ to (value of checkbox "Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom" as boolean)
    set USGWMKTZ to (value of checkbox "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom:" as boolean)

    if UKSTZ and USGWMKTZ then
        click checkbox "Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom"
        click checkbox "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom:"
        set theMessage to "   The target Zoom checkboxes are now not checked."
    else if not UKSTZ and not USGWMKTZ then
        click checkbox "Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom"
        click checkbox "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom:"
        set theMessage to "   The target Zoom checkboxes are now checked."
    else if UKSTZ and not USGWMKTZ then
        click checkbox "Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom"
        set theMessage to "   The target Zoom checkboxes were out of sync and are now not checked." & ¬
            linefeed & "   Run again to check the target Zoom checkboxes..."
    else if not UKSTZ and USGWMKTZ then
        click checkbox "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom:"
        set theMessage to "   The target Zoom checkboxes were out of sync and are now not checked." & ¬
            linefeed & "   Run again to check the target Zoom checkboxes..."
    end if

    delay 0.1

end tell

quit application "System Preferences"

return theMessage
```

---

To use the *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **macOS Mojave**, make the following change to the *code* shown above:

Change:

```
window "Accessibility"
```

To:

```
group 1 of window "Accessibility"
```

---

**What this *script* does:**

1. It *toggles* the *state* of the two *target checkboxes*.
2. If the *target checkboxes* are out of sync, it un-checks the one checked and returns a message.

The following shows the *command* run three times in **Terminal** to show its output. For demonstration purposes, in **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Zoom**, one of the *target checkboxes* is checked and the other is **not** checked.

```
$ ./togzoom
   The target Zoom checkboxes were out of sync and are now not checked.
   Run again to check the target Zoom checkboxes...
$ ./togzoom
   The target Zoom checkboxes are now checked.
$ ./togzoom
   The target Zoom checkboxes are now not checked.
$
```

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* used herein is just that and does not contain any additional *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

---

<sup>1</sup> While the `defaults` *command* can be used to modify `.plist` files nonetheless, in this particular case `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` can be difficult and getting the changes in this and aforementioned files requires programmatically killing the users `cfprefsd` *daemon* in an attempt to have the changes take effect. In some cases this process will fail and why scripting with AppleScript was chosen.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I wish `defaults write com.apple.universalaccess closeViewScrollWheelToggle` would work.

Comment: Is there a way to choose how much to zoom by, and where on the screen to zoom in on?